# Apex batch class start method not running

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

i have a batch apex class

```
 global class apexBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
 global final string query;
List<user>  lstUser= new List<user>();
Set<id>     setUserID= new Set<id>();



//constructor
global apexBatch () {
    if (system.Test.isRunningTest())
    {
        this.query='SELECT id FROM user limit 100';
    }
    else
    {
        this.query='SELECT id FROM user ;
    }
}


global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {

// do some processing


}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

}
```

I am calling this class from test class using this code

```
       Test.startTest(); 
    apexBatch ba = new apexBatch();

    Database.executeBatch(ba);
      Test.stopTest();
```

When i check the code coverage i can only see that the constructor is covered, the start and execute methods are not covered at all.

Any idea what could cause this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any exceptions in your debug log when you run tests? This is the exact same method I use for testing batch classes, so I took this code (I know it's simplified), added the missing close quote on the second query (I assume your code did save correctly and this isn't the problem!), and put the test code into a class, sure enough it's covered the batch code correctly.

Finally, I have seen some weird issues with test coverage reporting recently — how are you running the tests at the moment? I just ran all tests in the Org and got 90% coverage (it missed the second query line since for obvious reasons).

Comment: it was an exception thrown on my assert.  but wouldnt it cover the code if there is a assert failure?

Comment: Any testing after the assert wouldn't have happened which may have limited your coverage — the idea is that as well as covering code you use asserts to ensure that code is functioning as intended.